# Can't find Ceph when install on CentOS

Tags: docker, openshift, ceph, radosgw

I can't install Ceph on my centos 7 system.
The error message is like:

```
node.example.com][DEBUG ] This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

[node.example.com][DEBUG ] Determining fastest mirrors 
[node.example.com][DEBUG ] No package ceph available. 
[node.example.com][DEBUG ] No package ceph-osd available. 
[node.example.com][DEBUG ] No package ceph-mds available. 
[node.example.com][DEBUG ] No package ceph-mon available. 
[node.example.com][DEBUG ] No package ceph-radosgw available. 
[node.example.com][WARNIN] Error: Nothing to do 
[node.example.com][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 1 [ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to execute command: yum -y install ceph ceph-osd ceph-mds ceph-mon ceph-radosgw
```

Answer (score 2):

Below command install ceph mimic version 13.2

```
 ceph-deploy install  cephmon02 cephmon03  --repo-url=http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ceph/rpm-mimic/el7/
```

Changed mimic to another version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the ceph repo. first.

Refer the below link:

```
# yum install centos-release-ceph-jewel

# yum install ceph-{mon,osd,...}
```

https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/Storage